# Compiling OpenGL Assembly Language (ARB) assembly code

Tags: assembly, opengl, gpu

I have two questions to ask.

1. If I want to code in [ARB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARB_%28GPU_assembly_language%29), what are the prerequisites I need to write the code?
2. I have been using OpenGL and DirectX lately. I want to compile and run the ARB code. What compiler should I use to compile and run the code?

Answer (score 4):

It's no longer advised to code directly to assembly. It was important during Nvidia FX5xxx/Radeon 9700 era. A very long time ago. Now all shaders are compiled by drivers to extract max performance out of the platform.

Use OpenGL shading language, or use Nvidia Cg to generate an assembly from C++ like code.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I knew that ARB Assembly is Obsolete for graphics programming. But, i want to write a program which is independent of GPU make.

Comment: @Fr34K: GPU independence is what GLSL has been made for.

Comment: @Fr34K: Yeah, resorting to assembly for better cross platform/product compatibility is exactly the wrong way to approach the problem. You want higher abstraction level, not lower.

Comment: @Coder That's rather arrogant to assume you can say what someone wants, the OP is obviously asking about ARB-assembly not some abstracted alternative.